# Labels inside GAS macro

Tags: ios, assembly, gnu-assembler, openblas

I need to build `OpenBLAS` library of `iOS`. I've chosen to build `0.3.6` version of it. I believe that is the most updated stable version of the library.

You can find releases of this library here - https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases

I encounter next problem - it seems that assembly compiler provided by `clang` which can be found in `XCode` doesn't seem to understand certain syntax in `.S` files library provides.

I have two files (`nrm2.S` and `znrm2.S`) which cause all my troubles. Here's `nrm2.S`. I won't provide the other file because errors there is exactly the same. But if you want to take a look at it as well, I will post it, just let me know:

```
/*******************************************************************************
Copyright (c) 2015, The OpenBLAS Project
All rights reserved.
Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:
1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
distribution.
3. Neither the name of the OpenBLAS project nor the names of
its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE OPENBLAS PROJECT OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE
USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*******************************************************************************/

#define ASSEMBLER
#include "common.h"

#define N       x0
#define X       x1
#define INC_X       x2

#define I       x3

#if !defined(DOUBLE)
#define SSQ     s0
#define SCALE       s1
#define REGZERO     s5
#define REGONE      s6
#else
#define SSQ     d0
#define SCALE       d1
#define REGZERO     d5
#define REGONE      d6
#endif

/*******************************************************************************
* Macro definitions
*******************************************************************************/

.macro KERNEL_F1
#if !defined(DOUBLE)
    ldr s4, [X], #4
    fcmp    s4, REGZERO
    beq KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
    fabs    s4, s4
    fcmp    SCALE, s4
    bge KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@
    fdiv    s2, SCALE, s4
    fmul    s2, s2, s2
    fmul    s3, SSQ, s2
    fadd    SSQ, REGONE, s3
    fmov    SCALE, s4
    b   KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
    fdiv    s2, s4, SCALE
    fmla    SSQ, s2, v2.s[0]
#else
    ldr d4, [X], #8
    fcmp    d4, REGZERO
    beq KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
    fabs    d4, d4
    fcmp    SCALE, d4
    bge KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@
    fdiv    d2, SCALE, d4
    fmul    d2, d2, d2
    fmul    d3, SSQ, d2
    fadd    SSQ, REGONE, d3
    fmov    SCALE, d4
    b   KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
    fdiv    d2, d4, SCALE
    fmla    SSQ, d2, v2.d[0]
#endif
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
.endm

.macro KERNEL_S1
#if !defined(DOUBLE)
    ldr s4, [X]
    fcmp    s4, REGZERO
    beq KERNEL_S1_NEXT
    fabs    s4, s4
    fcmp    SCALE, s4
    bge KERNEL_S1_SCALE_GE_X
    fdiv    s2, SCALE, s4
    fmul    s2, s2, s2
    fmul    s3, SSQ, s2
    fadd    SSQ, REGONE, s3
    fmov    SCALE, s4
    b   KERNEL_S1_NEXT
KERNEL_S1_SCALE_GE_X:
    fdiv    s2, s4, SCALE
    fmla    SSQ, s2, v2.s[0]
#else
    ldr d4, [X]
    fcmp    d4, REGZERO
    beq KERNEL_S1_NEXT
    fabs    d4, d4
    fcmp    SCALE, d4
    bge KERNEL_S1_SCALE_GE_X
    fdiv    d2, SCALE, d4
    fmul    d2, d2, d2
    fmul    d3, SSQ, d2
    fadd    SSQ, REGONE, d3
    fmov    SCALE, d4
    b   KERNEL_S1_NEXT
KERNEL_S1_SCALE_GE_X:
    fdiv    d2, d4, SCALE
    fmla    SSQ, d2, v2.d[0]
#endif
KERNEL_S1_NEXT:
    add X, X, INC_X
.endm

.macro KERNEL_F8
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
    KERNEL_F1
.endm

.macro INIT_S
#if !defined(DOUBLE)
    lsl INC_X, INC_X, #2        // INC_X * SIZE
#else
    lsl INC_X, INC_X, #3        // INC_X * SIZE
#endif
.endm

.macro INIT
    eor v1.16b, v1.16b, v1.16b      // scale=0.0
    fmov    SSQ, #1.0
    fmov    REGONE, SSQ
    fmov    REGZERO, SCALE
.endm

/*******************************************************************************
* End of macro definitions
*******************************************************************************/

    PROLOGUE

    .align 5

    INIT

    cmp N, #0
    ble .Lnrm2_kernel_L999

    cmp INC_X, #0
    beq .Lnrm2_kernel_L999


    cmp INC_X, #1
    bne .Lnrm2_kernel_S_BEGIN

.Lnrm2_kernel_F_BEGIN:

    asr I, N, #3                // I = N / 8
    cmp I, xzr
    ble .Lnrm2_kernel_F1

.Lnrm2_kernel_F8:

    KERNEL_F8

    subs    I, I, #1
    bne .Lnrm2_kernel_F8

.Lnrm2_kernel_F1:

    ands    I, N, #7
    ble .Lnrm2_kernel_L999


.Lnrm2_kernel_F10:

    KERNEL_F1

    subs    I, I, #1
    bne .Lnrm2_kernel_F10

    b   .Lnrm2_kernel_L999

.Lnrm2_kernel_S_BEGIN:

    INIT_S

    mov I, N

    .align 5

.Lnrm2_kernel_S10:

    KERNEL_S1

    subs    I, I, #1
    bne .Lnrm2_kernel_S10


.Lnrm2_kernel_L999:
    fsqrt   SSQ, SSQ
    fmul    SSQ, SCALE, SSQ

    ret

    EPILOGUE
```

When compiler tries to handle that file, it gives me next errors:

```
<instantiation>:7:2: note: while in macro instantiation
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -O2 -DMAX_STACK_ALLOC=2048 -Wall -DF_INTERFACE_GFORT -fPIC -DNO_LAPACK -DNO_LAPACKE -DSMP_SERVER -DNO_WARMUP -DMAX_CPU_NUMBER=8 -DMAX_PARALLEL_NUMBER=1 -DVERSION=\"0.3.6\" -march=armv8-a -DASMNAME=_sgemm_oncopy -DASMFNAME=_sgemm_oncopy_ -DNAME=sgemm_oncopy_ -DCNAME=sgemm_oncopy -DCHAR_NAME=\"sgemm_oncopy_\" -DCHAR_CNAME=\"sgemm_oncopy\" -DNO_AFFINITY -I.. -UDOUBLE  -UCOMPLEX -c -UDOUBLE -UCOMPLEX ../kernel/arm64/../generic/gemm_ncopy_4.c -o sgemm_oncopy.o
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:14:22: error: unknown token in expression
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
                     ^
<instantiation>:7:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:14:22: error: invalid operand
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
                     ^
<instantiation>:7:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
../kernel/arm64/nrm2.S:87:16: error: unknown token in expression
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
               ^
<instantiation>:7:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
../kernel/arm64/nrm2.S:87:16: error: invalid operand
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
               ^
<instantiation>:7:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:4:21: error: unexpected token in argument list
 beq KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
                    ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:7:27: error: unexpected token in argument list
 bge KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@
                          ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:13:19: error: unexpected token in argument list
 b KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
                  ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:14:22: error: unknown token in expression
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
                     ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:14:22: error: invalid operand
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
                     ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
../kernel/arm64/nrm2.S:87:16: error: unknown token in expression
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
               ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
../kernel/arm64/nrm2.S:87:16: error: invalid operand
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
               ^
<instantiation>:8:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:146:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F8
 ^
<instantiation>:4:21: error: unexpected token in argument list
 beq KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
                    ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
<instantiation>:7:27: error: unexpected token in argument list
 bge KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@
                          ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
<instantiation>:13:19: error: unexpected token in argument list
 b KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@
                  ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
<instantiation>:14:22: error: unknown token in expression
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
                     ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
<instantiation>:14:22: error: invalid operand
KERNEL_F1_SCALE_GE_X_\@:
                     ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
../kernel/arm64/nrm2.S:87:16: error: unknown token in expression
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
               ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
 ^
../kernel/arm64/nrm2.S:87:16: error: invalid operand
KERNEL_F1_NEXT_\@:
               ^
/var/folders/xt/7v6bxk2n19zft1y3yzymdc580000gq/T/nrm2-bd3346.s:159:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 KERNEL_F1
```

While I was searching for an explanation of the issue I found this link - https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/labels-inside-macros . It gave me an understanding that troubled `\@` symbol is sort of label counter which handles the problem of unique label names inside `GAS` macro.

Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about Assembler and can not provide a fix to it on my own. So I figured maybe there're assembly gurus here who is willing to guide me through that "dark forest" .

Is there a chance that `\@` is relatively new symbol and Apple's compiler doesn't know about it yet? What should I do to fix that problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not so much "relatively new", but yeah clang/LLVM's assembler might not implement everything that GAS does.  It's also less forgiving of sloppiness.  I haven't looked at the details of your case to see whether it's bending the rules for GAS or what.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because clang uses the integrated LLVM assembler which doesn't have all the features of the GNU assembler.  Compile with `-no-integrated-as` to use the GNU assembler instead.

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work. I had an error `can't specifiy -Q with -arch arm64` multiple times

Comment: That's weird.  Please post the exact compiler invocation used.  Then add `-###` to the compiler invocation and post the output that results.

Comment: Actually, I found an ugly fix for that. You can find a discussion here - https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/2275 . Please feel free to chime in